# phonegap 3.5 wp8 geolocation

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1

I have a workfull application on android an iphone build with phonegap 3.5

In this application i use a watchPosition and it's work on android and iPhone. But now i want to use my application on a WP8.1 device.

So i have add the platform to my project and build it (works fine) but the watchPosition always return an empty position :

```
function startGeolocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    stopGeolocation();      // au cas ou deja lance
    mbdGlobal.geolocationWatchIdHighAccuracy = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        function (position) {
            alert("Position : " + JSON.stringify(position));
            mbdGlobal.lastMyPosition = position;
        },
        // next function is the error callback
        function (error) { displayGeolocationErrorMessage(error, 'GPS') },
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }
    );
}
else // finish the error checking if the client is not compliant with the spec
{
    alertWebapp(strMessageNotCompatible + "(geolocation)");
}
```

}

My alert display : Position : {};

I don't understand why in WP8 this doesn't work. I have add the ID_CAP_LOCATION on my app.

Plz if you know why it's doesn't work tell me.

Thanks you for all your answers.

edit : 
I also made a test app with the geoloc plugin and it's the same issue doesn't work.

Comment: This is something we are also experiencing and have no idea how to resolve this...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem as you, and have been stuck on it for a few hours. It turns out that JSON.stringify fails on the position object on WP for some reason. Using position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude works as expected though, so try alerting those. Note: alerting position.coords also brought back a blank string, you have to dig all the way into the specific property.